# Mobile app with TileMill offline map

Tags: android, iphone, titanium, tilemill

I need to build a simple map for offline use on mobile titanium app.

I found that the way to do it is with TileMill software, after reading some documents and watching some video what I understood is that you can import different layers to style with CSS like language.

http://techblog.troyweb.com/index.php/2012/11/a-mobile-app-with-offline-maps-using-titanium/

What I can't get is where I can export the basic terrain or street map to style on.
I don't really need to show special data, but just get the basic terrain map.

Answer (score 0):

> What I can't get is where I can export the basic terrain or street map to style on. I don't really need to show special data, but just get the basic terrain map.

You need to design the maps that you export, even if they're just existing examples like [osm-bright](https://github.com/mapbox/osm-bright) - MapBox's default tiles are online and are not exportable through TileMill.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MapBox's online editor to create a basic terrain map, and then call the map-id with the mobile SDK for offline maps. TileMill is only really necessary if you'd like to customize a terrain map beyond what's available on mapbox.com's editor.